# WordPress Twitter Bootstrap CSS Plugin - Updated, now nothing works

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, twitter-bootstrap

Just updated WordPress Twitter Bootstrap CSS Plugin to version Version 2.0.2.1.

Now all my Bootstrap styling has disappeared. I ran a force error and came back with:

```
Notice: Undefined index: page in /home2/mttwbshc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/hlt-bootstrapcss.php on line 161
```

I then referenced that line and it is as follows:

```
$sSubPageNow = $_GET['page'];
        if ( $sSubPageNow == 'hlt-directory') {
            echo '
                ';
        }
```

Is this a matter of referencing the wrong page? I'm a PHP noob, so that was really my best guess. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you always need a `index.php?page=something` or sometimes, you use only `index.php`?

Comment: Looks like after I updated it cleared my settings and excluded my CSS library. Problem resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to hear you had problems with this plugin (I'm the author). I don't know why it would have removed your settings - perhaps WordPress had a glitch and then deactivated the plugin.

The plugin is currently written (v2.0.2.1 and previous) to remove all plugin settings upon deactivation.

With the new version in development, version 2.0.3, I have changed default behaviour to NOT remove settings upon deactivation, and provided an option to change this in the configuration page.

Hopefully this will offset the problem you've experienced and allow  a bit more flexibilitry all-round.

Some heads up for the latest release too:
- Twitter Bootstrap LESS compiler for WordPress :)

Cheers!

Paul.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the problem you presented here, I have updated the code of the plugin so the latest version is now 2.0.2.3

The update removes the possibility of this particular error occurring and also now stops removal of all plugin options when the plugin is deactivated. The user configurable option to toggle this particular setting on/off will come with 2.0.3.

Of course, would love to hear any feedback you have on the plugin if you have any suggestions/questions (http://bit.ly/p4GmWR).

Thanks!
Paul.